# Adding events to dynamically created checkbox in jquery mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I created my check box dynamically in my page. i want to add click event for  all checkboxes 
that  dynamically created.

here is my code.

```
<div data-role="fieldcontain">
         <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" id="br">

        </fieldset> 
</div>
```

i dynamically created checkboxes and append to fieldset.

```
$.getJSON("http://localhost/WebSite/",
    function(data){ 
    var branchOp="";
      $.each(data.branch, function(i,item){   
         branchOp += '<input type="checkbox" name="branch" id="'+item.branchCode+'" value="'+item.branchCode+'" class="branch"><label for="'+item.branchCode+'">'+item.branchName+'</label>'; 
         $(item.branchCode).addClass("intro");     
      });
      $('#br').append(branchOp).trigger( "create" );  
      });
```

i use on(), live(), deligate() method to add event handlers on check boxes.

```
$('#br').delegate('click','input:checkbox', function(event) {
  alert('selected');
 }); 



$('#br').on('click','input:checkbox', function(event) {
alert('selected');
});
```

nothing is working for me...

Answer (score 38, accepted):

With checkbox / radio buttons, use `change` event.

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/vABvy/)**

```
$(document).on('change', '[type=checkbox]', function() {
// code here
});
```

Also, you can use `click` but on the div wrapping the checkbox.

```
$(document).on('click', 'div.ui-checkbox', function() {
  // code here
});
```

Comment: I followed your sample and it worked fine but only small thing. I am using asp.net mvc with razor and I created checkbox like this

<a Class="list-group-item" href="#" class="add">
    @Html.DisplayFor(Function(Model) Model.name)
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(Function(Model) Model.isSelected)
</a>

I dont get checkbox is checked when I click inside hyperlink. is your one works because you create checboxradio instead. I dont know what is the difference even thought:)

Answer (score 2):

For a dinamically added Button inside a Collapsible List (or anything) i do this:

```
$(document).on("click", "#listaEntrada input", function(evt) {
        var txSeleccionado = $(this).text(); //<-El Texto Seleccionado
        console.log(evt);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this, it's working for dynamically added checkboxes.

```
$(document).on("click", "INPUT[id^=checkboxId_]", function (event) {
   var targetId = event.target.id;

   if ($("#" + targetId + ":checked").length > 0) {
      alert('checked');
   }
   else {
      alert('unchecked');
   }
});
```